# How do I select a robot under PPR tree using DELMIA VBA?

Tags: vba, catia

I want to create a robot task for a specific robot under PPR tree using DELMIA vba. But I'm having trouble selecting the robot using its instance name. I've recorded the macro while changing the instance name of that robot (just to see how DELMIA does it) under PPR tree in Device Task Definition. But even the recorded code didn't work! Here's the code I've recorded:

```
Sub CATMain()

    Dim processDocument1 As ProcessDocument
    Set processDocument1 = DELMIA.ActiveDocument

    Dim product1 As Product
    Set product1 = processDocument1.GetItem("Resource") 'Runtime error '445' here

    Dim products1 As Products
    Set products1 = product1.Products

    Dim product2 As Product
    Set product2 = products1.Item("KR90 1.1")

    product2.name = "KR90 1.11"

End Sub
```

The program got stuck in the line where 'product1' is set. It says "Run-time error '445': Object doesn't support this action. ". 
Is there any way to select this robot using its name by any means?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.
ProcessDocument has products and Resources included. Robot lies in resources structure.

```
Set products1 =processDocument1.Resources
```

```
Set product2 = products1.Item("KR90 1.1")
```

If it is in subtree you need to go down till the product level above robot.